# Definition of totally ordered monoid?

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, monoid, ordered-groups

Suppose I have the monoid $(\mathbb{N},\times)$.

It is my understanding that for the relation $\le$ to form a total order on the above monoid, the following must be true:

$$a\le b\iff (\forall c\in\mathbb{N})\ a\times c\le b\times c$$

If that is the case, then I could plug in $10$ for $a$, $5$ for $b$ and $0$ in for $c$ and arrive at a contradiction:

$$\begin{align}
10\le5&\iff \ 10\times 0\le 5\times 0\\
F&\iff \ 0\le 0\\
F&\iff \ T\\
\end{align}$$

However if instead the definition was (if vs iff):

$$a\le b\implies (\forall c\in\mathbb{N})\ a\times c\le b\times c$$

Then the contradiction I showed goes away (the right hand side becomes vacuously true). So which is the right definition? Or really, which is the more useful definition?

Comment: It is a monoid - $1$ is the identity. It doesn't have *inverses*, but that's a different story.

Comment: Right, let me correct that!

Comment: Hmm, to me "totally ordered" would tend to mean $\forall a, b, a \le b \vee b \le a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a logical error in your argument: In $$a\le b\iff (\forall c\in\mathbb{N})\ a\times c\le b\times c$$
you cannot "plug in" something for $c$, as the $\forall$ is not at the top level.

Consider that:

- "I am 12 feet tall iff for every person $x$, $x$ is a mathematician" is true, because I am not 12 feet tall and there are people who are not mathematicians.
- "I am 12 feet tall iff Jean-Pierre Serre is a mathematician" is false, because I am not 12 feet tall but Jean-Pierre Serre is a mathematician. So "plugging in" Serre for $x$ is not valid.

---

For a monoid $(M,\times)$, which definition you use doesn't matter, as the two definitions you propose are actually equivalent. This is because the implication
$$a\le b \Longleftarrow (\forall c\in M)\ a\times c\le b\times c$$
is always true: assuming $(\forall c\in M)\ a\times c \le b\times c$ we can plug in $c = 1$ to obtain $a \le b$.

For a general magma, the $\Longrightarrow$ definition is probably the "right" one and as far as I can find, it is the only one that is used. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_semigroup

Comment: In my example I 'plugged' $0$ in for $c$ to show that there existed a natural number $c$ such that $a\le b\not\equiv a\times c\le b\times c$. I don't see how what you wrote is always true. It seems to only be true if $c=1$ or whatever the identity element is.

Comment: You have only shown that $(\forall c\in\mathbb{N})\ (a\le b\iff a\times c\le b\times c)$ is false, but that is not equivalent to $a\le b\iff (\forall c\in\mathbb{N})\ a\times c\le b\times c$. ("For all people x, I am 12 feet tall iff x is a mathematician" is false.) You can only plug things into "for all" statements if the "for all" applies to the whole statement.